# How can I send POST request using WKWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**My Problem**: I cannot send `POST` request using `WKWebView` in iOS.
The server cannot obtain the body of the request, and I couldn't find a solution from previous `StackOverflow` posts.

**What I've Done**:
The code related to creating a request for webview is like below:

```swift
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mycompany.com/request")!))
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.httpBody = "api_key=XXX&id=123".data(using: .utf8)
urlRequest.addValue("\(urlRequest.httpBody?.count ?? 0)",
                    forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
urlRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8",
                    forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

var webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)
webView.load(urlRequest)
```

Also, I've tried with `cURL` and `Android` webview and everything works fine.

Working `cURL` command:

```sh
curl -v POST "https://mycompany.com/request" -d "api_key=XXX&id=123"
```

---

Also, I've tried to debug the webview using `Safari` in `macOS` but for some unknown reason, the debugger detached from the app with an exception, and the `Safari` inspector couldn't show anything.

[image]

I'm using this configuration to initialize the webview:

```swift
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences = preferences
```

---

**Update**: I tried the code below without any success:

```swift
let json = [
    "api_key": "XXX",
    "id": "123",
]
urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
```

---

**Update**: I thought it might be related to string encoding. So, I replaced the data of the `POST` request that works with `cURL` with the data of the request in the iOS project (hardcoded the data string), but it didn't work as well.

---

**Update**: I compared `cURL` request with the iOS webview request.

This is the result of the `cURL` request:

```
curl -v POST "https://mycompany.com/request" -d "api_key=XXX&id=123"

> POST /request/ HTTP/1.1                                
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0                                                        
> Host: mycompany.com                                                 
> Accept: */*                                                                    
> Content-Length: 114                                                            
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

This is the result of the iOS webview request which intercepted using `WKNavigationDelegate` in debug mode:

```
po navigationAction.request

▿ https://mycompany.com/request
  ▿ url : Optional<URL>
    ▿ some : https://mycompany.com/request
      - _url : https://mycompany.com/request
  - cachePolicy : 0
  - timeoutInterval : 60.0
  ▿ mainDocumentURL : Optional<URL>
    ▿ some : https://mycompany.com/request
      - _url : https://mycompany.com/request
  - networkServiceType : __C.NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
  - allowsCellularAccess : true
  ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
    - some : "POST"
  ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>
    ▿ some : 5 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : "User-Agent"
        - value : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "Content-Length"
        - value : "114"
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : "Origin"
        - value : "null"
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - key : "Accept"
        - value : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
      ▿ 4 : 2 elements
        - key : "Content-Type"
        - value : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8"
  ▿ httpBody : Optional<Data>
    ▿ some : 114 bytes
      - count : 114
      ▿ pointer : 0x00007f978948dee0
        - pointerValue : 140288820043488
  - httpBodyStream : nil
  - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
  - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Comment: The data set to httpBody is not JSON-serialized.

Comment: @ElTomato I tried `JSON` Serialization too as you said, But didn't help. I updated my post.

Comment: "I've tried with cURL " What's your cURL working command? Also, you specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but send JSON? That doesn't make sense. So `urlRequest.httpBody = "api_key=XXX&id=123".data(using: .utf8)` should work if it's really that encoding, and not JSON.

Comment: @Larme This is the working `cURL` command: `curl -v POST "https://mycompany.com/request" -d "api_key=XXX&id=123"`. I tried `urlRequest.httpBody = "api_key=XXX&id=123".data(using: .utf8)` but it didn't work. I updated my post as well.

Comment: Were u able to get the solution, m having exactly same issue